# Digit grouping while typesetting many-digit numbers

Tags: siunitx

I am well aware of the `siunitx` package, but as far as I can tell, it comes short for this task.

In decimal notation, there are many conventions such as using `.` or `,` for the decimal mark, as well as using a space, `.` or `,` for group delimiters. The package handles them well, and also makes them configurable too, which is a great help. But...

It does not allow defining a group size different than the most-conventional one: three. Seems fine at first, but when looked at [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use) at Wikipedia, one can see that people may actually need some flexibility there.

On top of that, it keeps using that magical number three for the digits after the decimal mark, too. This is the part where I am personally concerned of, the three on the first part is actually fine by me (for the time being), which I have brought up only due to its close relevance.

According to this [question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182775/convention-of-digit-grouping-after-decimal-point), the prevailing convention is even to make groups of 5 when it comes to digits after decimal mark.

So, is there a `siunitx` option to change this three to something else, even to different things on both sides of the decimal mark? If there isn't, what could be done to have groups of three on the left side and of five on the right side?

Is there perhaps a way for me to manually mention the group limits for `siunitx` to see and consider (maybe through enabling a switch), just like I mention the decimal mark? In an example:

```
\num[flick]{123 456.12345 67890}
```

to produce:

[image]

Here, supposedly space characters were to be interpreted as places where I'd like to see each one of my group-delimiters, which are left as the default thin-space (?), thanks to that option `flick` I had been looking for.

Sorry for a suggestion-like question.

Comment: That table includes the SI ones. Hence does siunitx too. The rest is not SI

Comment: @percusse Then again `siunitx` also shows some flexibility, too. And then again, that table doesn't show much about the grouping of digits after decimal mark for any, including SI.

Comment: what are the constraints? does the macro have to be expandable? will it be supposed to expand its argument, possibly doing computations onit? will it have to accept numbers in scientific notation too? ... if you just need something accepting explicit decimal numbers `ABC...YZ.abc...yz` and grouping the digits before and after the mark in a specified repetitive manner, this can be done quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Found some code in `siunitx.sty`

> ```
> \cs_new_protected:Npn \__siunitx_number_format_group_decimal_aux:NNNN
>   #1#2#3#4 {
>   \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2}
>     { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl {#1} }
>     {
>       \tl_if_empty:nTF {#3}
>         { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl { #1 #2 } }
>         {
>           \tl_put_right:Nn \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl { #1 #2 #3 }
>           \tl_if_empty:nF {#4}
>             {
>               \tl_put_right:NV \l__siunitx_tmpb_tl \l__siunitx_group_sep_tl
>               \__siunitx_number_format_group_decimal_aux:NNNN #4
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Now you can see how it works: every time **siunitx** encounter a decimal part, say, 3.`14159265`, it tries to read four arguments. In this case,

- it will get `1`, `4`, `1`, and `59265`. So it inserts an `\l__siunitx_group_sep_tl` and saves `141,` into `\l__siunitx_tmpb_tl`.
- Next `59265` becomes `5`, `9`, `2`, and `65`; and `\l__siunitx_tmpb_tl` becomes `141,592,`.
- Finally `65` becomes `6`, `5`, empty, and empty. So it stops here and return with `\l__siunitx_tmpb_tl` being `141,592,65`.

### So?

It seems like even with **expl3** this kind of processing is hard to be replaced by a loop. If you want a different grouping size, try to do something like

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siunitx_number_format_group_decimal_aux:NNNNNNN
 #1#2#3#4#5#6#7 {
  {}
  {
    {}
    {
      {}
      { 
        {}
        {
          {}
          {
            {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```